# How to exclude lines with ... in regular expression

Tags: regex

I have the following table of contents and sections in my file:

```
1.2 Purpose .................... 8  
1.3 System Overview ............ 8  
1.4 Document Overview .......... 8  
1.5 Definitions and Acronyms ......... 9  
2.1.3.3.8   FOO 
2.1.3.3.9  BAR 
2.1.4 TEST
```

I'd like to extract the section names and ignore the lines that are part of the table of contents.

I've been trying this regular expression:

```
^((?:\d{1,2}\.)+(?:\d{1,2})+)\s.+(?!\.\.\.).*$
```

However, I keep capturing the table of contents lines.

How can I exclude the lines with the .... strings?

Thanks!

Comment: It is line by line.I'd like \1 to contain the section numbers from the non TOC lines.

Comment: Does the section names do not have `...` afterwards?

Comment: No.  They do not.  Only the TOC lines do.

Comment: Because you had a `.+` earlier, and a `.*` later, the original could actually choose any position it wanted to find a place where `(?!\.\.\.)` wouldn't match -- and if it found any single such place, you'd get a hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here was that you were only excluding `.`s at a very specific place; your negative lookahead match didn't go beyond the position it was placed in. Consider instead:

```
^(\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})*)\s*[^.]*(?!.*\.{3}).*$
#                                  ^^
```

...the characters with the carrot below them are critical: They make the negative lookahead apply not only at that specific point, but at anywhere after it as well.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you!

Comment: This one is a bit easier for the engine, I believe: [`^(\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})*)\s*(?!.*\.{3,}).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/mP4lZ6/1).

Comment: @stribizhev, good call -- better to consume any whitespace available to be consumed before making the negative assertion; actually, could consume any non-period content from consideration the same way.